# Reading a json object as a single row pandas df

Tags: json, pandas

I have a json object of the following format

```
{
  "ABC": 123,
  "DATE": "2020-01-01",
  "AMOUNT": 100,
  "IDENTIFIER": 12345
}
```

I want to read this into pandas as a single row df. So the output should look like

```
ABC    DATE        AMOUNT    IDENTIFIER
123   2020-01-01   100        12345
```

For now, I am OK if all the data is read in as strings, I can change the type in the df.
I have tried `df=pd.read_json('file.json', orient='index')` but this results in a df which I have to pivot (and renaming columns seems to be a challenge as well as the column names are rangeindex).
Any thoughts on a more cleaner way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you well
as I understood you need to convert JSON object like this

```
{
  "ABC": 123,
  "DATE": "2020-01-01",
  "AMOUNT": 100,
  "IDENTIFIER": 12345
}
```

to dataframe, you can read the file and then pass the records to the pd.DataFrame like this

```
import json
data = open('file.json').read()
df=pd.json_normalize(json.loads(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

The safer way of doing this is using a `with` statement:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('file.json') as f:
    df = pd.json_normalize(json.load(f))
```